# One cache for two applications Yii

Tags: php, yii

Yii Framework 1.1.14

I create two applications admin.site.ru and site.ru, and use memcache.

How to make one cache for two applications?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the same keys in both applications when calling `Yii::app()->cache->set($key, $value, $duration)`
2. Use the same [key prefix](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CCache#keyPrefix-detail) in both applications: `Yii::app()->cache->keyPrefix`

The above will cause exactly the same memcache keys to be generated in both applications which means you are now sharing the same data between multiple yii apps.

Comment: remember not to use file cache on this scenario

Comment: @tinyBite I'm curious to know why file cache should not be used in this case?